# how to make typecasting for double datatype variable to integer in vba excel macro 2013.....without using the keywords

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to typecast double(32 bit) datatype value to 8 bit value but it shows overflow
I used `cbyte()` for type conversion.. I tried it on excel 2013

```
ReadDtcBSM(ucDtcCounter).DTC(2) = cbyte((DTCNumber And 255))
'DTCNumber  value is 4294967295
```

I expect output of `255` but actual output is overflow

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm missing the point, but doesn't 4294967296 with a bit mask of 255 yield 0? And 429496729**5** yields 255?

If your VBA is 64-bit, then you could coerce a `LongLong` for the conversion (indicated by the caret after 255). That would prevent the overflow error.

```
Dim d As Double

d = 4294967296#
Debug.Print CByte(d And 255^)
```

If you're stuck with 32-bit, then it might be easier to iterate the first 8 bits:

```
Function ToByte(ByVal dbl As Double) As Byte
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 7
        ToByte = ToByte + (dbl - 2 * Int(dbl / 2)) * 2 ^ i
        dbl = Int(dbl / 2)
        If dbl = 0 Then Exit Function
    Next

End Function
```